How to verify merkle root with batch root and its adjacent_leaves inside a pallet?
I am using below code to create Merkle Root.
pub type MmrRootHash = H256;
pub fn create_merkle_root(leaves: Vec<MmrRootHash>) -> MmrRootHash {
            sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256::trie_root(
    leaves
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, l)| ((i as u32).encode(), l.encode()))
        .collect()
);
        }

I want to verify Merkle Root of a leaf with its batch root and adjacent_leaves. Can somebody help me to provide library for the same?

fn verify_merkle_root(root: MmrRootHash, batch_root: MmrRootHash, adjacent_leaves: Vec< MmrRootHash >) -> bool {

..

}





@bkchr Can you please help me to provide the solution?
